Jacobian Notation question
Wikipedia has the following notation.  How does 1 change to 2?
#1:
$\mathbf{J_f} = \frac{\partial(f_1,..,f_m)}{\partial(x_1, ..,x_n)}$
#2:
$\mathbf{J_f} = \begin{bmatrix}
  \dfrac{\partial \mathbf{f}}{\partial x_1} & \cdots & \dfrac{\partial \mathbf{f}}{\partial x_n}
\end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix}
  \nabla^{\mathrm T} f_1 \\  
  \vdots \\
  \nabla^{\mathrm T} f_m   
\end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix}
    \dfrac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_1} & \cdots & \dfrac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_n}\\
    \vdots                             & \ddots & \vdots\\
    \dfrac{\partial f_m}{\partial x_1} & \cdots & \dfrac{\partial f_m}{\partial x_n}
\end{bmatrix}$
For #1 I had thoughts of distributing $\partial$ across $f_n$ then dividing similarly, but this doesn't appear to arrive at #2 because of canceling. Maybe the Cartesian product of numerator and denominator?

It's more or less a definition as a whole, similar to how $dy/dx$ is not a fraction but an expression defined as a whole.
